# How to implement actionbar search in listview of arraylist hashmap?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

[image]
my design is like this.

On my main activity i am calling onQueryTextChange

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmain, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                    adapter.filter("");
                    listview.clearTextFilter();
                } else {
                    adapter.filter(newText);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This is my list adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView rank;
        ImageView flag;

        TextView hq;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        hq = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hq);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        rank.setText(resultp.get(SplashScreen.COMAPANY_NAME));
        hq.setText(resultp.get(SplashScreen.HQ));


        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SplashScreen.COMPANY_LOGO), flag);

        return itemView;
    }

    // Filter method
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
 //
//
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

what will be the logic to search a item inside the listview that contain arraylist hashmap.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
     //
    //
                        }
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

I see many answers for arraylist string, but that questions will not solve my problem, please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.Declare a global BackupList inside the adapter, e.g.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mBackupData = new ArrayList<>();
```

2.In adapter constructor, copy ALL DATA into BackupList, e.g.

```
mBackupData.addAll(arraylist);
```

3.Make a public method that: clear DataList; Loop through BackupList and add items that match the condition into DataList; Notify the Adapter for changed, e.g.

```
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    data.clear();
    for (HashMap hm : mBackupData) {
        if (((String)hm.get("MapKey")).contains(charText)) {
            data.add(hm);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Note: DataList refers to where you get data in getView(). If the DataList will be changed by Fragment/Activity, then in the Adapter code, need to create another public method that update the items to BackupList also.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Take one `tempData` in order to filter your data

```
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> tempData = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Copy data of `resultp` into `tempData` in your contructor.

```
public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        tempData = new HashMap<>(mData);
}
```

User filter method to filter data

```
public void filter(String charText) {
    data.clear();
    if (charText.length() > 0) {
        for (String hm : tempData) {
            if (hm.contains(charText)) {
                data.put("key", hm);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (String hm : tempData) {
            data.put("key", hm);
        }
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifying the adapter that datSet has been changed...
}
```

Comment: thank you fr your response, here you are copying the data tempData.add(r), which cannot be possible because its a hashmap

Comment: I guess you are so sure, you must have reason. May I ask?

Comment: I was talking about this
for (HashMap<String, String> r :
                    data) {
            tempData.add(r);
        }
 as tempData is a hashmap we cannot use tempData.add(r)

Comment: aah Okay, I thought it is arrayList.